# Getting InvalidParameterInput in cloudformation template deployment

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am getting below error when tried to deploy cloudformation temaple for aws dashboard..

I used awsdashboard as one of resource in cft along with some other alarm. Seems Alarms going fine, but dashboard having below error.

```
"The field DashboardBody must be a valid JSON object (Service:
AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
InvalidParameterInput;"
```

Code Snippet: (I have additional widgets to below , but I mentioned only one)

```
AWSDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardName: !Sub "awsdashboard"
      DashboardBody: !Sub '{"widgets": [
        {
            "height": 6,
            "width": 6,
            "y": 0,
            "x": 9,
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "view": "timeSeries",
                "stacked": false,
                "metrics": [
                    [ "AWS/S3", "BucketSizeBytes", "StorageType", "StandardStorage", "BucketName", "abc-${Env}-abc-${AwsRegion}", { "period": 86400 } ],
                    [ ".", "NumberOfObjects", ".", "AllStorageTypes", ".", ".", { "period": 86400 } ]
                ],
                "region": "${AwsRegion}",
                "title": "abc-s3-bktsz-numrofobjects",
                "period": 300
            }
        },
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is invalid json, so you have to fix it. You have only showed some fraction of your code, so no one will be able to assist.

Comment: Also, you're setting a string a value for DashboardBody. Not a json object.